# Omitting property annotation for objects

Tags: typescript

Im trying to create a locale strings object:

```js
const strings = {
  hello: {
    en: 'hello',
    pl: 'hej'
  },
  bye: {
    en: 'bye',
    pl: 'pa'
  }
}
```

This works, if i type `strings.` intellisense shows me theres `hello` and `bye` available. However this doesnt enforce anything, some properties could be missing `en` or `pl` or even have other that dont exist. To make it more specific I declared an enum and typed the object:

```js
enum Language {
  en = 'en',
  pl = 'pl'
}

type Strings = { [k: string]: { [lang in Language]: string } }

const strings: Strings = {
  // ...same as before
}
```

Great! Now my `strings` properties are properly typed. But wait, now I lost typings on the properties because of `[k: string]`. Now `strings.dontExist` is ok according to ts (understandable).

So my question is how do I achieve inferred properties (just like in the first example) but also strongly typed properties that are explicitly set by me (`{ [lang in Language]: string }`)?

[using typescript 3.6.2]

Answer (score 1):

While I think that you'd have a much easier time typing if you turned your structure around (e.g putting the `en` and `pl` on the top level), I think you have to create the object first and then infer the type of the keys into a new object, like so:

```js
enum Language {
  en = 'en',
  pl = 'pl'
}

type Translation =  { [lang in Language]: string } 

const strings  = {
  hello: {
    en: 'hello',
    pl: 'hej'
  },
  bye: {
    en: 'bye',
    pl: 'pa'

  }
}

type TranslationGroup =  keyof typeof strings;

const typed: Record<TranslationGroup, Translation> = strings

typed.foo //error
```

Comment: Thanks, i was hoping its possible without creating an additional object. What do you recommend for the reversed structure? Wouldnt that mean i have to have some sort of a list of all of the keys?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just make `Strings` generic in the keys `K`, like this:

```
type Strings<K extends string> = { [P in K]: { [L in Language]: string } };
```

And then you could use a small helper function to infer `K` from your object literal without forcing you to retype it:

```
const asStrings = <K extends string>(s: Strings<K>) => s;
```

It works like this:

```
const strings = asStrings({
  hello: {
    en: "hello",
    pl: "hej"
  },
  bye: {
    en: "bye",
    pl: "pa"
  }
}); // Strings<"hello" | "bye">
```

And you should get errors if you leave a language out.  Hope that helps!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAMghiA5mOjhQN4CgpVFAXigCJRiAaHKABwBtCS7isBfLLAFwE9r0BlDgCcAlkgDOAHgDSeAB4dQAEzFQxQ0YgB8DDFADaABSiioUgLoAuTPpjGQsBMlTBLq9UigtPAbiwBjAHsQNSg4MQERcQZpOQUQZTdIrQAKMSsIjUkpTQBKQm0xX38gkLUklSIwjPFk7FwAC2BaWgCrOtw8ECtiRuaAiipcOm7GgCtmXBZKXAAjLmA2wc7uueABjppabuo4Cc9WHO8oAHpjqGrESR6mluIoAB8SVeJNLCA)